# How to debug Ionic2 app using VS Code on Android Device

Tags: ionic2, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Ionic 2 and VS Code. I'm able to debug in a chrome browser. How do I debug on an android device?

I'm new to VS Code but I believe that I need to add a configuration to launch.json like I did for Chrome. What does that configuration look like and are there any other parameters that need to be set?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/issues/238).

Delete existing launch.json file from .vscode directory and go to Debugger and click on setting icon it will show you installed debuggers and select one of them...

Only I deleted the entire .vscode directory. I then selected Cordova as the debugger and then launch.json populated with the correct configurations. Previously it was not populating. Now I select the "run android on device" press debug and everything works perfect. Breakpoints set in VS Code are being hit.

Nice!

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, please mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who meet the same issue.

Comment: yes that is it! Very easy after I installed the "Cordova Tools" Extension in VS-Code.